# mysql output in html table- shell script

Tags: html, mysql, shell, unix

I am executing one mysql query returning two columns in shell script

```
TABLES=$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST $MDB -e "SELECT table_name, ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS table_size FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'inventory' AND CREATE_TIME < DATE(NOW()) -INTERVAL 7 DAY" | awk '{ print $1}' | grep -v '^table_name' )
```

How can I store it in a 2d array and display the result as html table?

As a work around I am executing two mysql queries and storing the result in two separate arrays

```
    TABLES=$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST $MDB -e "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'inventory' AND CREATE_TIME < DATE(NOW()) -INTERVAL 7 DAY" | awk '{ print $1}' | grep -v '^table_name' )

    declare -a TABLE_SIZE=($($MYSQL -u $MUSER -p$MPASS -h $MHOST $MDB -e "SELECT ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS table_size FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'inventory'  AND CREATE_TIME < DATE(NOW()) -INTERVAL 7 DAY" | awk '{ print $1}' | grep -v '^table_size' ))
    #IF there are no tables in databse
    if [ "$TABLES" == "" ]
    then
            echo "Error - No table found in $MDB database!"
            exit 3
    fi
    i=0
    for t in $TABLES
    do
            #echo "Deleting $t table from $MDB database..."
            str="<tr><td> $t </td><td>${TABLE_SIZE[$i]}</td></tr>"
            i=`expr $i + 1`
            table_array+=$str
    done
    table_array+="</table>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have `mysql` do this for you with the `-H` option and `-N` option if you do not want column names.

```
mysql -H -N -u $MUSER -p $MPASS -h $MHOST $MDB < your_sql
```

If you need additional html customization, you can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the internal file separator to newline.
IFS=$'\n'

echo "<table>"

# Loop over each row.
for line in $(mysql -N ... < your.sql)
do
  echo "  <tr>"

  # Set the internal file separator to space/tab.
  IFS=$' \t'

  # Create columns array.
  columns=($line)

  echo "    <td>${columns[0]}</td>"
  echo "    <td>${columns[1]}</td>"

  echo "  </tr>"
done

echo "</table>"
```

Comment: But how can i store it in a 2d arry and process  it to display in html?

Comment: Not sure you need a 2d array, but I've updated answer to include a way to access each column.